# Run JavaScript function after the first function completes applying CSS styles to an element - callback not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

As shown in the snippet, I have two buttons. When either button is clicked, the following should happen in this order: (1) colour changes to red, (2) button is hidden (3) alert box with the button ID is displayed.

I have tried passing function2 as a callback parameter to function1 but what actually happens is the alert box gets displayed first and then the button disappears without the colour change.

I don't understand why this is happening. Any help/tips would be appreciated!

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener("click", function() { function1(this.id, function2); });
}

function function1 (uid, callback) {
  document.getElementById(uid).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById(uid).style.display = "none";
  callback(uid);
}

function function2 (clicked_id) {
  alert(clicked_id);
}
```

```html
<p>Clicking on a button should change its color to red, hide it and then display an alert box with the button's ID:</p>

<div class="main">
 <button id="btn1" class="buttons">Button 1</button>
 <button id="btn2" class="buttons">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the browser's UI thread (which is the thread your JavaScript code runs on) time to repaint the page before you stop the world with `alert`. Or better yet, don't use `alert` at all.

You can *usually* get away with delaying it by one event loop cycle via

```
setTimeout(callback, 0, uid);
```

...but not always. The most effective way I've found to date (but I don't have to do this often, because I don't use the stop-the-world functions `alert`, `confirm`, or `prompt` often) is to use the `setTimeout` inside a `requestAnimationFrame` call:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    setTimeout(callback, 0, uid);
});
```

The outer callback is called just before the browser is ready to repaint after your changes have been applied, so we schedule a call *after* that.

Updated Snippet:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener("click", function() { function1(this.id, function2); });
}

function function1 (uid, callback) {
  document.getElementById(uid).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById(uid).style.display = "none";
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    setTimeout(callback, 0, uid);
  });
}

function function2 (clicked_id) {
  alert(clicked_id);
}
```

```html
<p>Clicking on a button should change its color to red, hide it and then display an alert box with the button's ID:</p>

<div class="main">
 <button id="btn1" class="buttons">Button 1</button>
 <button id="btn2" class="buttons">Button 2</button>
</div>
```